# How can I create array of files in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, io

In a C/C++ program, is it correct for me to do this:

```
int i;
FILE **files = malloc(numFiles * sizeof(FILE *));
std::string file("foo"), ext(".bar");
char *num[10];

for (i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
    files[i] = fopen((file + itoa(i, num, 10) + ext).c_str(), "w");
}
```

This is basically what I am doing, but I am not getting anything written to the files. They're blank.

### EDIT

I have fixed my problem. I thought I might be doing something wrong here, but it turned out to be elsewhere. Thanks for the responses, anyway.

Comment: Is it C or C++? If you're already using `std::string`, why not other C++ features instead of, say, raw arrays.

Comment: Well, there are no output operations in the code you've shown...

Comment: This is an apparently correct, if ugly, C++ (not C or C/C++) fragment. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: In my experience, C++ is ugly however you write it. I am not a huge fan.

Comment: @Luke: It's certainly ugly if you try to blend it with C idioms like that. In my opinion, it can be rather elegant (if occasionally somewhat twisted) if you stick to native idioms.

Comment: I was trying to stick almost purely with C (this is for a library which makes functionality from a C++ class available to a separate C program, so that seemed sensible). However, string concatenation in C is a complete nightmare. Hence the use of std::string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure they are blanked, you did not write anything, you simply open the file in writing mode!

You have to use the fwrite or fprintf function to write the data to the file and then close the file with fclose.

Comment: or use ofstream and ofstream.operator<<() method.

Comment: I am just asking if this initialization is correct. I am writing to the files elsewhere. Don't know whether it's this that is the problem.

Comment: Would ofstream make this much easier?

You'll have to excuse me, I am usually a C programmer. Not too familiar with ++.

Comment: If you're compiling C++, you need to cast the result of `malloc` (which is `void*`). And `itoa` is a non-standard function. Other than that, code seems ok.

Comment: @Luke, the initialization is correct if no error will happen. Do you use `fclose` function somewhere?

Comment: Show a self-contained complete program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @elyashiv: Performance is one good reason not to use the C++ stream classes. The C equivalents are not as easy to set up and use, but they often work faster. This could be an important consideration, as reading and writing output streams is slow to begin with.

Comment: @AlexReynolds the C equivalents are faster primarily because iostreams are synced with the C equivalents. If you call `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` at the beginning of your program, they will operate independently and they will be roughly the same speed.

Answer (score 2):

You have array of pointers to char. But you need array of char.
`char *num[10];` --> `char num[10]`.

I am wondering how it isn't crashing :)

Comment: That was just a typo... it's not like that in the real program.